# Bootstrap and CSS' transform

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, input

I am trying to make a contact form in the center of a website, but for some reason, **Bootstrap** and CSS' **`transform: translate(-50%, -50%);`** (used for absolute positioning in the center of a website) doesn't play well with each other.

**The problem**: When both Bootstrap and CSS-transform is applied, the top-line/margin of the input field is removed, making the input field look bugged.

I can remove either the Bootstrap link (HTML line 2) or transform (CSS line 6) and it will look as intended, but I need both Bootstrap (for responsive design) and transform (for center positioning).

JS Fiddle (notice **HTML: line 2** and **CSS: line 6**):

https://jsfiddle.net/t1txvv9d/

Hope anyone know a workaround for this? I would really appreciate help. Thank you.

Comment: Does [this](https://jsfiddle.net/ksiabani/t1txvv9d/3/) works for you?

Comment: I have posted an answer, thanks. Glad it helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are better off with flex:

```
body, html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ksiabani/t1txvv9d/3/) and more about CSS Flexbox [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

Answer (score 1):

I would clean up the code a bit: Remove the `margin-right: -50%;` (has no effect), add `position: relative` to `.container` and also add a height or at least a `min-height` setting to `.container` (depending what you are up to, a fixed px value or a percentage, which then also requires a height definition for the parent elements)

https://jsfiddle.net/b7Lry34n/1/

[image: Image of JSFIDDLE after comments]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried to look at your example and also mess a bit with it, but as far as I can see, the problem still exists? Top element of input is still missing on my screen at least..

Comment: Hmm - it's vertically centered here and quite far away from the top (?)

Comment: Here is how it looks on at my screen: https://ibb.co/hE3nhF (Notice the top line of input is missing).

Comment: You should post your full code, there's something *outside* of the code you posted which causes this.

Comment: Ok I will consider that, but since the problem is existing from both the JSFiddle we both posted (at least on my screen), then it shouldn't be necessary to post full code? Correct me if I am wrong...

Comment: When I look at the js fiddle (the one I posted), the input is perfectly centered - I added a screenshot to my answer

Comment: That is indeed a bit weird. I will try to mess around with it and if I can't get it working, then I'll make a new post with full code. Thank you for your help and inputs :)